# RSpec unit testing an eigenclass: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, eigenclass

I'm trying to test the method `cumulative_cost` in my `Product model`.

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def cumulative_cost
      self.sum(:cost)
    end
  end
end
```

So I'll run something like `Product.where(name:"surfboard").cumulative_cost` Let's say it returns two records, one with a cost of 1000, and another of 150, it'll return `=> 1150`.

So here's what I've written as a test.

```
RSpec.describe Product, "class << self#cumulative_cost" do
  it "should return the total cost of a collection of products"
    products = Product.create!([{name:"surfboard", cost:1000}, {name:"surfboard", cost:150}])
    expect(products.cumulative_cost).to eq(1150)
  end
end
```

Then when I run my test, it fails.

```
undefined method `cumulative_cost' for #<Array:0x007fe3e31844e8>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't believe someone would vote this amazing question down, anonymously!!! True troll form.

Comment: I balanced it for you :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from K M Rakbul Islam's answer...

products is an array because that's what `Product.create!` with a supplied array returns.

Your test should be...

```
expect(Product.where(name:"surfboard").cumulative_cost).to eq(1150)
```

Comment: Yes, SteveTurczyn deserves it :-)
I spent more time explaining the problem before giving the correct answer :P

Comment: SteveTurczyn, one +1 from me too :)

Answer (score 2):

`cumulative_cost` is a class method on `Product` model. So, you have to call it like: `Product.cumulative_cost`.

The error is saying:

```
undefined method `cumulative_cost' for #<Array:0x007fe3e31844e8>
```

which means, you are calling this `cumulative_cost` method on an array but it's not implemented on array objects, hence it's getting this error.

Change your expectation to: (according to SteveTurczyn's answer)

```
expect(Product.where(name:"surfboard").cumulative_cost).to eq(1150)
```

Comment: Ok, I get that. Why isn't it a collection of ActiveRecord Objects? And how do I create these two buildings as a collection?

Comment: You are calling `create!` method on `Product` with an array param, so it reutns an array back to the `products`. Use this: `expect(Product.where(name:"surfboard").cumulative_cost).to eq(1150)`

Comment: It's a team effort. :)